# Blower works when the thermostat is on "COOL" and "FAN ON" rather than on "COOL" and "AUTO."

Tags: thermostat, cooling, blower

I have the old AC outdoor 567G and furnace 394G system. Several days ago it started working when thermostat was on "cool" and “AUTO.”  But after several minutes the blower inside the furnace stopped sending any air in the house.  I approached the AC outdoor unit and found out that its fan blades became separated from its hub so that the fan doesn’t cool the condenser - The unit was damaged.
However, it is not clear what made the furnace blower stop working. The furnace and AC systems are connected only by the thermostat terminal. So that the blower should have continue working (of course, it will not be a cooled air). But the blower is not damaged; it works on the thermostat “Fan ON.”
I would be thankful if someone explains what made the blower stop when the AC outdoor unit became damaged.
After I installed  new blades and the AC unit start working fine. the  furnace blower sends a cool air in the house only when "FAN ON." With "cool " and "AUTO" the blower dosn't work. But it works well with "HEAT and AUTO" (of course, when the thermostat is set on  the temperature higher than in the room). It is not clear how to fix  the problem with the blower  motor not working with "AUTO."

Comment: It's good that you've provided model numbers, but brands would be helpful too. You can [edit] that into your question

Comment: First guess: a pressure switch showed the indoor unit that it wasn't getting what it expected from the outdoor unit.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your indoor unit please?

Comment: Sounds like Bryant.

Comment: Yes, this is Bryant system. As to "a pressure switch, I don't know where it is situated. The wiring diagram shows: single phase system,

Comment: 2. A pressure (limit)  switch relates mostly to furnace problems. It is not clear how a hot refrigerant from the condenser ( for several (2-5) minutes) can hurt  the electric circuitry. 3, The wiring diagram for the Bryant AC and furnace system is on the Internet. But this is not its circuitry  which would be more useful.